# Load image in Libharu by HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile()

Tags: c++, libharu

I am trying to load a PNG image using LibHaru libraries. The Libharu provides the `HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile()` method to load an image as per the [**Documentation**](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/API:-Document#HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile).

**PROBLEM:** I get a linker error when I put the following line in my code

```
HPDF_Image inHPDF_Logo = HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile(pdf, "E:/images/logo.png");
```

Error: `LibHaru.lib(hpdf_image_png.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol png_set_strip_16 referenced in function LoadPngData`

**PS:** I am using VS2010 and I already have LibPNG.lib and LibHaru.lib added to the linker